# Increase the payment profiles limit beyond 10 in AuthorizeNet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, credit-card, authorize.net

How can I increase the limit on the payment profiles in AuthorizeNet? I get this error message when I go beyond the limit of 10.

```
E00042 - You cannot add more than 10 payment profiles.
```

Comment: You cannot, the gateway does not support more than 10 payment profiles per customer profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Authorize.Net's description](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/) about the Customer Information Manager (CIM), it appears CIM only supports 10 payment profiles but up to 100 shipping profiles per customer profile.

"CIM supports customer profiles that include billing, payment and shipping information. Each profile is stored on our secure servers and assigned an ID that is used in place of all customer information. **Each customer profile can include up to 10 payment profiles and up to 100 shipping profiles.**"

Comment: How can I remove them if I want it from my sandbox mode?